# How to get a smooth transition with a looping carousel in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-redux

I have been trying to have a smooth transition when I reposition pictures using CSS in react in a looping carousel.

As you can see in the following codepen, when you press up, only the last image smoothly transitions to the first position, the others jump forward.

When you press down, only the first four images smoothly transition to their new position, and the first one jumps to the last position.

https://codepen.io/JeffHernandez/pen/mxJqdp

Here is my css

```
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms linear;
  -moz-transition: all 200ms linear;
  -ms-transition: all 200ms linear;
  -o-transition: all 200ms linear;
```

I think my issue has to do with reordering the image object, which I'm currently doing with the following functions.  I am using slice to create a new object so I don't change the reference type in the current state.

```
moveUp() {
  let items = this.state.items.slice();
  items.unshift(items.pop())
  this.setState({items})
}

moveDown() {
  let items = this.state.items.slice();
  items.push(items.shift())
  this.setState({items})
}
```

I was under the impression that using a consistent key value would fix this, but it has not worked.  I might need to approach this another way but I'm not sure.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

---

**EDIT:** I was able to figured it out.  https://codepen.io/JeffHernandez/pen/odNeNY

I was replacing the classes instead of just modifying the values.  I was able to accomplish this by using styled components

Answer (score 1):

I think reordering images is not the best solution. I'd rather tried to change classes based on "currently active".

```
class VerticalCarousel extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          items: images,
          currentActive: 0 //initially, current active is top slide, 
                           //images[0] element
        }
    }

    changeSlide = (direction) => {
          let nextSlide;
          if (direction === 'up') {
              nextSlide = this.state.currentActive - 1
          } else {
              nextSlide = this.state.currentActive + 1
          }
         // aslo you have to set rules for boundary conditions when 
         // currentActive is [0] and "Up" button clicked
         // or currentActive is the last element in array and "Down" clicked
         this.setState({ currentActive: nextSlide });
    };

   render() {
     return(
        <div className="absolute">
            {this.state.items.map((item, index) => 
                <Image data={item} currentActive={this.state.currentActive} 
                 index={index} key={index} />
            )}             
          <div>
          <button onClick={() => 
             {this.changeSlide('up')}}className="buttonUp">Up</button>
          <button onClick={() => 
             {this.changeSlide('down')}}className="buttonDown">Down</button>
          </div>
      </div>
     )
   }
}
```

To avoid mess in the main component let's separate Image. It should contain some logic to set classes. General idea is to have `"active"` class on `currentActive`, `"bottom"` for all next `"previous"` -  all above elements in your case. Also you may need some additional classes to specify `currenActive-1` and `currentActive+1` elements. You'll get a pattern like this:

`.previous` - `.previous.top` - `.active` - `.bottom.next` - `.bottom`
(don't forget about  boundary conditions)
Than adjust you styles based on this.

```
class Image extends React.Component {
  render() {
     let position = ''
      let index = this.props.index
      let currentSlide = this.props.currentActive
       if (index === currentSlide) {
            position = 'active'
       }
       if (index > currentSlide) {
            position = 'bottom';
            if (index === currentSlide + 1) {
                position = `${position} next`
            }
       }
       if (index < currentSlide) {
                position = 'top';
                if (index === currentSlide - 1) {
                    position = `${position} previous`
                }
       }               
       let classList = `animate image ${position}`           
       return 
             <img key={this.props.key} src={this.props.data.image} className={classList}/>
      }
    }
```

Here is the rough [mock](https://codepen.io/Yulia_pi/pen/GdKway?editors=0110) of described approach. Play around with styles and transitions to achieve the effect you are expecting

P.s. I've used this solution for my own react Carousel slider. Here is [working demo](http://yuliapi.github.io/projects/carousel/index.html?utm_source=github&utm_campaign=carousel)  and [code source](https://github.com/yuliapi/carousel-carousel-react)

Comment: Thanks! this is great information.  Creating a variable that will watch the current active element is a great approach.

Unfortunately, if I'm interpreting this correctly, this does not provide the looping aspect I need as it sets boundaries on the first and last image.  I need that looping aspect which is part of the reason this has been so difficult.

Again, though, very solid approach.  This is a great way to construct a carousel.  Thank you!